# Как получить модифицированную модель таблицы?

Tags: jtable, java

Написал на основе `AbstractTableModel` свою модель и добавил в неё один дополнительный метод. Переписывая в `jTable` метод `getToolTipText` натолкнулся на то, что не могу добраться до этого метода.

Подскажите, как лучше сделать, чтобы можно было обратиться к нему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте, что ваш добавленный метод объявлен как public.
2. В переписываемом методе `getToolTipText` сделайте необходимое приведение типа для

.

```
TableModel:
MyTableModel tm = (MyTableModel)getModel();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я последовал Вашему совету и заработало.